# ubuntu 15.10 gnome automatic logout, back to login screen. Crash in Syslog

Tags: gnome, login, 15.10, ubuntu-gnome

I am using Ubuntu 15.10 with GNOME Shell 3.18.2 and very often my system automatic logout with blank screen and come back to login screen. Not seen any crash logs. But seen crash log in syslog.

Syslog can be find under following location:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/14476968/

Xorg.0.log log
http://paste.ubuntu.com/14477096/

Is there any work-around for this issue. Please let me know if I need to provide any further info on the same.

Thanks!

Comment: @All any comments or work-around?

Comment: How much disk space do you have free? Is the drive ok? X segfaulted but there were errors writing files before that.

Comment: @bain, udev            2.8G     0  2.8G   0% /dev <br/>
tmpfs           573M  9.5M  563M   2% /run  <br/>
/dev/sda7        92G   19G   69G  22% /  <br/>
tmpfs           2.8G  9.5M  2.8G   1% /dev/shm  <br/>
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock  <br/>
tmpfs           2.8G     0  2.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup  <br/>
/dev/sda8        56G   50G  3.8G  93% /home  <br/>
/dev/sda1       496M  302M  195M  61% /boot/efi  <br/>
tmpfs           573M   12K  573M   1% /run/user/116  <br/>
 . Yes drives are OK. Pls let me know if I need to provide any logs for the same Thank you!

Comment: Could be [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1510723), some segfault that affects 4.3. The backtrace is odd. You would need to follow instructions [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Backtracing) to install "debug symbol information" then log in remotely and attach with gdb to see if you can get a proper backtrace. Or there may be some backtraces in logs, check /var/log/Xorg.*.log.

Comment: @bain, looks like there is some underline issue is triggering and related to below issue, which I have raised bug: #1539386 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/plymouth/+bug/1539386 BTw, Thank you for your inputs

Comment: Any help @user with the issue. I am facing same issue since I installed ubuntu 15.10. Please share if you found the solution.

Comment: @Wazzzy As of now there is no solution for this problem. Between, I have upgraded my gnome shell to GNOME Shell 3.18.2(upgraded to development build). Probably, yon can try doing the same